# keyDown not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem a problem with my code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currenty = 0;
var currentx = 0;
$("body").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 68) {
        $(".box").animate({marginLeft: currenty + 30}, 200);
        currenty += 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 65) {
        $(".box").animate({marginLeft: currenty - 30}, 200);
        currenty -= 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 87) {
        $(".box").animate({marginTop: currenty + 30}, 200);
        currentx += 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 83) {
        $(".box").animate({marginTop: currenty - 30}, 200);
        currentx -= 30;
    } else {

    }
});
});
```

My problem with this code is that when i press a key, nothing happens.

EDIT: It seems to work if i change the first keycode to 32 (spacebar)

EDIT AGAIN: Just solved my problem, the keycode's where for capital letters

Comment: What errors appear in your browser's console?

Comment: Only event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: I think that here works http://jsfiddle.net/VZ5c6/

Comment: You seem to have a lot of confusion between `currentx` and `currenty`. In the latter two cases, you increment X, but you always animate based on Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `keydown` instead. `keypress` returns 100 not 68 for the letter d.

Test the differences [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events).

Comment: Just realised you said this. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Make sure you test in different browsers as well. (The page I linked is very useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Use document instead of body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currenty = 0;
var currentx = 0;
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 68) {
        $(".box").animate({marginLeft: currenty + 30}, 200);
        currenty += 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 65) {
        $(".box").animate({marginLeft: currenty - 30}, 200);
        currenty -= 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 87) {
        $(".box").animate({marginTop: currenty + 30}, 200);
        currentx += 30;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 83) {
        $(".box").animate({marginTop: currenty - 30}, 200);
        currentx -= 30;
    } else {

    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still doesn't solve my problem, im still gonna use document instead though. :)

Comment: can you give me your html also ?

Comment: All i have inside my body tags is <div class="box"></div>